# How to fix "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders." React-Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to load a react-leaflet map but I receive error like this:

```
    Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   useEffect(function updatePathOptions() {
|     if (props.pathOptions !== optionsRef.current) {
>       const options = props.pathOptions ?? {};
|       element.instance.setStyle(options);
|       optionsRef.current = options;
```

**1.** I import components from library:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker } from 'react-leaflet';
```

**2.** I try to use the map in the same app.js file:

```
<MapContainer
    className="markercluster-map"
    center={[51.0, 19.0]}
    zoom={4}
    maxZoom={18}>
    <TileLayer
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    />
  </MapContainer>
```

Can I get example how to use leaflet map or How to fix this error ?

Comment: perhaps it's the nullish coalescing operator that is triggering the error

Comment: Is there a way to fix this problem >?

Comment: just add .babelrc setting to project maybe fixed

Comment: search for babel nullish coalescing operator

Comment: Ali Najafi you mean to use npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react ? https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react

Answer (score 0):

in your project install this moduals in package.json:

```
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.2.0",
```

then
remove @react-leaflet forler in node-moduales
in your system with cmd in any folder

git clone https://github.com/hqdung99/maps-leaflet-youtube.git

when finish goto the folder this node-modules and copy this folder @react-leaflet and past into the Previous node-modules folder

Answer (score 0):

if you use craco like this in package.json

```
  "scripts": {
 "start": "craco start",
```

change to

```
  "scripts": {
 "start": "react-scripts start",
```